# Opening a JavaScript based Android app remotely using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm writing a JavaScript based Android application (using PhoneGap) to track patients' compliance with their medical regimen. This requires the app to run in the background and remind the patients at specified times to take their medication. Since PhoneGap based apps do not run in the background, I was wondering if I could remotely start the app on the patients' phones (assuming I have their permission, of course) using NodeJS (which I'm using for this app anyway - to gather the compliance data).

Alternately, I was wondering whether I could trigger a dialog box on the mobile phone remotely using NodeJS.

I'm sorry if these questions sound silly... I'm new to this stuff.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a socket or a listener on their phones (pointing to your nodejs server), this will cost their battery... also you have to create those modules you need(a dialog box, module to start the app) inside your app... once that you have all that you can trigger the app and show the dialog you want

Comment: The battery cost is acceptable... most of the patients have been told about that. As regards the rest of the suggestion, while it makes complete sense, I'm not sure how to begin going about it. It would be great if you could give me a couple of pointers.

Comment: If you use cordova, there is a plugin for background mode: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode and it works very well.

Comment: This looks like just the thing. Many thanks.